# Spring Security session concurrency

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have an app build with Spring 4.0 and Security 3.2 and I want to implement session concurrency but it does not seems to work. All other aspects of security are working just fine. Here are my xml configs:
first of all in my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

then in my security.xml

```
<security:http  auto-config="false" 
                use-expressions="true"
                authentication-manager-ref="authManager"
                access-decision-manager-ref="webAccessDecisionManager"
                entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">             

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/agent/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_AGENT')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />       
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"
                                 invalid-session-url="/public/login.xhtml"/>

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/public/login.xhtml" 
                     invalidate-session="true" 
                     delete-cookies="true"/>
    <security:expression-handler ref="webExpressionHandler"/>

    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
</security:http>
```

and

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/public/login.xhtml" />
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
   p:defaultFailureUrl="/public/login.xhtml" />

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

 <bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="/session-expired.htm"/>       
</bean>

<bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
</bean>  

<bean id="authManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>  
            <ref bean="myCompLdapAuthProvider"/>        
            <ref bean="myCompDBAuthProvider"/>
        </list>     
    </property>     
</bean>
```

My UserDetails implements hashCode() an equals() and with all this the concurrent session limitation does not work. After a little debug session I have observed that my session is never found in sessionRegistry and I guess that this is the main reason, but I do not know why!?
Any idea of what I`m doing wrong here ?

P.S. I have such records in my debug logs:

```
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 2 of 11 in     additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
(FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /resources/images/icons/connection_on.gif at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:107) - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@96cf68e: Principal: MyUserDetails [username=adrian.videanu, dn=org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter: dn=cn=Adrian Videanu,ou=IT,ou=Organization .....
```

so the filters are invoked...

Updates

I can see that the session creation event is published because i have this line in logs :

```
(HttpSessionEventPublisher.java:66) - Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionCreatedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3827a0aa]
```

but i never hit registerNewSession method from SessionRegistryImpl as I guess it should. Also the HttpSessionEventPublisher is invoked when I initially open the login page because I guess that`s when the session is created, but then after I enter the credentials and push submit HttpSessionEventPublisher is not invoked anymore.

Updates 2
As a test I have injected SessionRegistryImpl to one of my beans in order to try to access some of its methods:

```
@Named
@Scope("view")
public class UserDashboardMB  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

public void init(){

    System.out.println("-- START INIT -- ");
    List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

    System.out.println("Principals = "+principals);

    for (Object p:principals){
        System.out.println("Principal = "+p);
    }

    System.out.println("-- STOP INIT -- ");
}   
}
```

and the output is :
INFO: -- START INIT --
INFO: Principals = []
INFO: -- STOP INIT --
so, nothing is populated there.

Update 3
I have replaced "sas" bean with the one provided by Serge but it still doesn`t seems to work. I have neabled the debugger again and I thing that the problem is that on class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter at method doFilter() none of my requests are processed as it should.Here is a part of doFilter():

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        return;
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Request is to process authentication");
    }

    Authentication authResult;
// rest of method here
}
```

From what I see in the debugger my requests doesn't seems to require auth and chain.doFilter(request, response); is invoked.

Update 4
I guess i found the issue. The filter is not running as it should because the filterUrl param is not the proper one. As i read in the docs:

> This filter by default responds to the URL /j_spring_security_check.

but my login part is implemented with JSF managed beans and actions. Now, my login form is at /public/login.xhtml and the url that the login info are posted is the same. If I set this as filterUrl I have problems because is called at the intial form rendering also and I have a infinite loop there as no user/password are set up.
Any idea how to overcome that ?
This is how my LoginManagedBean looks like:

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class LoginMB implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authManager")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

// setters and getters

public String login(){

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    try {
        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword());
        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

        // perform some extra logic here and return protected page
        return "/agent/dashboard.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                        
        logger.error("Auth Exception ->"+e.getMessage());
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Invalid user/password");
        fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        context.addMessage(null, fm);                   
    }
    return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not only the filters are invoked, but the SecurityContextHolder is correctly populated. As it is on a `permitAll` url, your session is correctly registered. How did you verify that concurrent session limitation does not work ?

Comment: Hi Serge, the test was simple, i have logged in with two different browsers with the same credentials. I was expected that when i try to login with the second browser an error message/page would appear, but not, i can login with both browsers without any problem

Comment: You found another trap in spring security : for the filter to work, the login form **must** post to a different URL : it does not ignore GET requests but either catches or rejects them. My own form contains a `<form action="/.../j_spring_security_check" method="POST">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to fix the issue. The problem was due to my mix setup between spring standard filters and custom jsf login form. I have left in my xml conf only the "sas" bean as Serge pointed out and the in my LoginMB I have manually and programmatically invoked the  SessionAuthenticationStrategy onAuthentication() method. So now my LoginMB looks like:

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class LoginMB implements Serializable {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authManager")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Inject
@Qualifier("sas")
private SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy;


public String login(){

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    try {
        Authentication authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword());
        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(result, httpReq, httpResp);

        // custom logic here 

        return "/agent/dashboard.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

    }catch(SessionAuthenticationException sae){
        sae.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Auth Exception ->"+sae.getMessage());

        String userMessage = "Session auth exception!";
        if (sae.getMessage().compareTo("Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded") == 0){
            userMessage = "Cannot login from more than 1 location.";
        }

        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(userMessage);
        fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
        context.addMessage(null, fm);
    }       
    catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                        
        logger.error("Auth Exception ->"+e.getMessage());
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Invalid user/password");
        fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
        context.addMessage(null, fm);                   
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now the sessions are registered and session limitation is working.

Answer (score 9):

There is a slight difference between spring security 3.1 and spring security 3.2 concerning concurrency session management.

The old `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` is now deprecated. It checked if the number of concurrent sessions was exceeded and registered sessions in a `SessionRegistry` for future use.

It has been *partially* replaced in 3.2 by `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`. It effectively controls if the number of concurrent sessions is exceeded **but no longer registers new sessions** (even if javadoc pretends to : I looked in the source code to understand it!)

The registration of sessions is now delegated to `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy`! So for session concurrency to work, you have to use both. And the example in 3.2 reference manual, effectively uses for bean `sas` a `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` containing a `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`, a `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` **and a `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy`**!

For the whole thing to work, you just have to replace your `sas` bean with:

```
<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
                <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: It still doesn't seems to work, I`ll update my question with details.

Comment: I had exactly this problem, used an example from Spring security 3.1 but I am using a newer version. Already had several headaches, many thanks!

Comment: Hi Serge, How I can resolve the casting issue ? error I got - Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy] to required type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy] for property 'sessionAuthenticationStrategy': no matching editors or conversion strategy found